# Complete dataframe for few samples, from a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

```
DF=structure(list(Ech = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L), pos = c("BD", "BG", "HD", "n_BG", "n_HG", "BD", "HD", "HG", 
"n_BG", "n_HG"), sm = c(5, 4, 2, 6, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1)), .Names = c("Ech", 
"pos", "sm"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Ech", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:4, 5:9), group_sizes = c(5L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(
    Ech = c(4L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Ech", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Ech"))
```

The full list of pos value is :

```
column=c("BD","BG","HD","HG","n_BD","n_BG","n_HD","n_HG")
```

these value shoulg be present for each `Ech`. I'm aiming to convert this dataframe:

From

```
  Ech   pos    sm
   <int> <chr> <dbl>
 1     4    BD     5
 2     4    BG     4
 3     4    HD     2
 4     4  n_BG     6
 5     4  n_HG     1
 6    13    BD     4
 7    13    HD     1
 8    13    HG     1
 9    13  n_BG     2
10    13  n_HG     1
```

to (complete

```
  Ech   pos    sm
   <int> <chr> <dbl>
 1     4    BD     5
 2     4    BG     4
 3     4    HD     2
 4     4    HG     0
 5     4  n_BD     0
 6     4  n_BG     6
 7     4  n_HD     0
 8     4  n_HG     1
 9     13   BD     4
 10    13   BG     0
 11    13   HD     1
 12    13   HG     1
 13    13 n_BD     0
 14    13 n_BG     2
 15    13 n_HD     0
 16    13 n_HG     1
```

So I used :

```
DF = DF %>%
complete(column=c("BD","BG","HD","HG","n_BD","n_BG","n_HD","n_HG"),nesting(pos,Ech))
```

> Error :`by` can't contain join column `column` which is missing from RHS

How to do this ?

Comment: Please take the time to list non-base R packages that you are using in your question or by adding the tags. It will help others including those who might propose an answer as well as future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  mutate(pos=factor(pos, levels = c("BD","BG","HD","HG","n_BD","n_BG","n_HD","n_HG"))) %>% 
  complete(pos, fill = list(sm = 0))
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   Ech [2]
     Ech    pos    sm
   <int> <fctr> <dbl>
 1     4     BD     5
 2     4     BG     4
 3     4     HD     2
 4     4     HG     0
 5     4   n_BD     0
 6     4   n_BG     6
 7     4   n_HD     0
 8     4   n_HG     1
 9    13     BD     4
10    13     BG     0
11    13     HD     1
12    13     HG     1
13    13   n_BD     0
14    13   n_BG     2
15    13   n_HD     0
16    13   n_HG     1
```

If the data is not grouped by `Ech` one have to use instead:

```
complete(Ech, pos, fill = list(sm = 0))
```

From the help.

- Factors: the full set of levels (not just those that appear in the data) are used.
- Continuous variables: you may need to fill in values that don't appear in the data like in **docendo discimus** comment under this post.

Comment: Or `DF %>% complete(Ech, pos = all_pos_vector, fill = list(sm = 0))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus ok yes. A little bit more straightforward.

Comment: your solution only works when the data is grouped by `Ech`-column before this operation. This is the case for the sample data but perhaps not clear for other people seeing this post later. The other option is to include `Ech` in the complete statement as I did